# How do I smartly subset an array in R with dynamic dimensions?

Tags: arrays, r, simulation, subset

I'm crafting a simulation model, and I think this problem has an easy fix, but I'm just not that used to working with arrays. Let's say I have an array, `Array1`, that has 3 dimensions. The first two are of constant and equal length, `L`, but the third dimension can be of length from 1 to X at any given time.

I want to be able to periodically subset `Array1` to create a second array, `Array2`, that is composed of *up to* the last Y "sheets" of `Array1`. In other words, if the length of the third dimension of `Array1` is greater than Y, then I want just the last Y sheets of `Array1` but, if it's less than Y, I want all sheets of `Array1`.

I know that I can crudely pull this off using the tail function and a little finagling:

```
tmp1 = tail(Array1, (L*L*Y))
Array2 = array(tmp1, dim = (L, L, (L*L/length(tmp1))))
```

But it seems like there could be a more elegant way of doing this. Is there an equivalent of `tail` for arrays in R? Or is there a way that `Array2` could be produced via simple logical indexing of `Array1`? Or perhaps the `apply` function could be used somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you after something like this?

```
a <- array(1:(3*4*5), dim=c(3,4,5))
x <- dim(a)[3]
y <- 2
a[, , seq(to=x, len=min(x, y))]

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   37   40   43   46
[2,]   38   41   44   47
[3,]   39   42   45   48

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   49   52   55   58
[2,]   50   53   56   59
[3,]   51   54   57   60
```

Comment: Hello @Hong Ooi, thanks for responding. I could be wrong, but I think your code works well for my needs except that your `x` may need to be replaced with `dim(Array1)[3]` in both spots so that it can handle circumstances where `Y > dim(Array1)[3].`

Comment: Huh? `x` is equal to `dim(Array1)[3]`.

Comment: Oh, whoops, yes it is, my mistake. This worked very nicely, thanks!